# Combine overflow "auto" and "visible" (overflowing content to be visible)

Tags: html, css

When having an element with the option `overflow: auto`, the overflowing content is hidden.

The option `overflow: visible` keeps the content visible.

Is there an option to have both combined, to have the content scrolling, but overflowing?
Here's some code where I have a sandbox where I show both possibilities: https://codepen.io/SimonSimCity/pen/YzRjjvm

Comment: that doesn't sound logical, how can you scroll a visible content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native setting for a visible scoll overflow. You would have to build one yourself.

The idea is to have a container that spans the full width of the page (or whatever the visible area should be) and then use some tricks to make the content only span the part you want it to be.

One way is to use padding:
https://codepen.io/errnesto/pen/PoxByQx

(I took some shortcuts here by using position: absolute on the outer container.)

There are also other ways to achieve this effect. If you don't like the scroll bar spanning the full page you could listen to the `wheel` event and move the content with js. Although I would always prefer not to implement scolling by yourself.